# check if ntfs disk is mounted with cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, ntfs

In my computer, I have a ntfs network disk, and with cygwin and bash I have some automatic script (post-commit git hooks) for copy information to the ntfs disk.

with bash (in cygwin), how I can check if the ntfs is enable ?

Comment: What do you mean by `enabled`? i.e. mounted, can be written to, etc... Also is there something specific about [tag:cygwin] that you've tried that's preventing you from doing it?

Comment: @BroSlow yes, if the ntfs network disk, is mounted

Comment: What's the relevant info for the disk if you run `mount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if mount | grep -q /path/to/device/or/mount/point ; then
  # it's mounted
else
  # it's not
fi
```